# How to use openssl aes algo to encrypt every frame

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

As title says, I want to encrypt every frame captured by `OpenCV` using `OpenSSL` AES algorithm.

Now I have frame data which I call `frame_data`. And type of `frame_data` is `std::vector<unsigned char>`. **Obviously its length or size is not fixed.**

I can encrypt and decrypt 16 bytes data.For example:

```
unsigned char key[16] = {'0'};

unsigned char plain_text[16] = {'1'};
std::vector<unsigned char> cipher_vec(16);
std::vector<unsigned char> decrypt_vec(16);

AES_KEY aes_enc_ctx;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_enc_ctx);
AES_encrypt(plain_text, cipher_vec.data(), &aes_enc_ctx);

// aes decrypt
AES_KEY aes_dec_ctx;
AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &aes_dec_ctx);
AES_decrypt(cipher_vec.data(), decrypt_vec.data(), &aes_dec_ctx);
```

So how can I encrypt `frame_data` using `OpenSSL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong functions. The AES_* functions are low-level crypto primitives and should only be used if your really know what you are doing.

The preferred approach for encryption/decryption is to use the OpenSSL EVP_* functions. Specifically `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()`, `EVP_EncryptUpdate()` and `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` as well as the similarly named decrypt functions. These can accept variable size input.

The man pages for these functions are available here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit_ex.html

There are some examples here:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

You will need to select an appropriate mode for the encryption algorithm (e.g. GCM, CCM, OCB etc), and then pass the appropriate cipher to the EVP_EncryptInit_ex() function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try it.